# Select range of two columns which are also greater

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a case where there is a table with order value and those limits and ranges like below

```
Id       Value       Range_From         Range_To

1        360.0         500               1000
2        1001.0        1001              2000
3        3000.0        1001              2000
```

I need an output of 3rd record where the 2nd and 3rd records fall between 1001 and 2000. But when I query that using SQL BETWEEN I am only getting the record 2 because that is falling under Range_From and Range_To for Between condition.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Value BETWEEN Range_From AND Range_To;
```

The above query will only give the 2nd record. How to get the third record as this is also satisfying the condition.

Also I only need to get the record as output which ever value is highest and it should also fall in the Range_From and Range_To

Comment: If your condition should match the 2nd and 3rd column, why do you write the query about `value` column?

Comment: It will only return record 2 based on your condition. 

You have to read it like this:

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Value BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000;
&
Value 3000 is not between those ranges.

You have to specify the value of the 'Value' field in the where clause

Comment: To be more clear,  I only need to get the record as output which ever value is highest and it should also fall in the Range_From and Range_To

Comment: You need to explain why you think 3000 is between 1000 and 2000

Comment: @Strawberry Correct me if this will not fall under 1000 and 2000. But I definitely need to check the range condition.

Comment: Correct you how? What should the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want below query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT value, row_number() over(order by value desc) as RN FROM Table WHERE Value BETWEEN Range_From AND Range_To; 
) A WHERE RN = 1
```

You won't be able to get the 3rd row because it doesn't satisfy the condition. 3000 is not between 1001 and 2000

Comment: But this will not work in MySQL, It will work in SQL Sever

Comment: modified my answer. Pls try. I can't down vote your question. I have low reputation also.

Comment: hey @Shanthanu365, you should write down more about your question because its may be confusing to all. as per Jervs, he is write that 3000 is not between 1001 and 2000 so You won't be able to get the 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Value > Range_To);

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but above query will also returns 2nd record as well.

Comment: what is the data type of Range_From AND Range_To ?

Comment: you want only greater record ?

Comment: Try SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Value > Range_To);